# How to add 2 OpenLayer Marker Animations to page? Clickevent seems to be overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, openlayers-3

I have an [OpenLayer Marker Animation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html) implemented in my (python) flask application.

However in my dataset that I am using for the Marker Animation I have an extra route that I would like to show an animation of as well.

When I add code to take care of the second animation it is like the controls for the first animation is overwritten and I have no idea of how to avoid this from happening. I've tried renaming all the vars to 1 and 2 to avoiding them from overwriting each other, but for some reason it seems like it still overwrites the controls.

I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gat2oogz/2/) to illustrate the problem. If you click the start animation under Map 1 it will run the animation on Map 2. I have just used the procedure below in my fiddle, but originally I had the code in a for-loop that was run twice to extract both routes and then draw the maps.

```
Route points for Map 1
Set up Map 1
Bind functions to Map 1 buttons

Route points for Map 2
Set up Map 2
Bind functions to Map 2 buttons
```

I guess my problem is about isolating code and/or bindings. First I tried renaming the functions (moveFeature, startAnimation, stopAnimation) to their respective names with either a "1" or "2" added. That did not do the trick, nor did renaming all the variables similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a lot of variables with the same name. For example, when you overwrite the function StartAnimation, the buttons enter in the second one (Since both are pointing to a function called "StartAnimation").

To avoid this, you have to create different variables for each map. This way you would avoid unuseful code and can be sure that each element is using the variables they are supposed to use.

I've built an example based on your jsfiddle code:

```js
var locations1 = [[53.44241609, 6.84913974], [53.44241894, 6.84913726], [53.44242156, 6.84913385], [53.44242473, 6.84913076], [53.44242859, 6.84912721], [53.44243324, 6.84912446], [53.44243724, 6.84912303], [53.44243994, 6.84912206], [53.44244199, 6.84911994], [53.44244474, 6.84911928], [53.44244757, 6.8491193], [53.44245181, 6.84911968], [53.44245596, 6.84912085], [53.44246139, 6.84912072], [53.4424669, 6.84912142], [53.44247222, 6.84912279], [53.4424778, 6.84912454], [53.44248644, 6.84912644], [53.44249062, 6.84912761], [53.44249409, 6.84913057], [53.44249746, 6.84913362], [53.44250197, 6.84913592], [53.44250901, 6.84913629], [53.44251198, 6.84913792], [53.44251293, 6.84913988], [53.44251458, 6.84914126], [53.44251596, 6.8491434], [53.44251778, 6.84914727], [53.44251988, 6.8491501], [53.44252248, 6.8491531], [53.44252517, 6.84915473], [53.44252316, 6.84915181], [53.44252377, 6.84915124], [53.4425233, 6.84914949], [53.44252341, 6.84914848], [53.44252276, 6.84914827], [53.44252397, 6.84914868], [53.4425216, 6.84914477], [53.44252001, 6.84914287], [53.44252107, 6.84914273], [53.44251986, 6.84913869], [53.44251841, 6.84913463], [53.44251482, 6.84912822], [53.44251525, 6.84912649], [53.4425148, 6.84912465], [53.44251483, 6.84912049], [53.44251625, 6.84911749], [53.44251677, 6.84911403], [53.4425187, 6.84910978], [53.44252028, 6.84910694], [53.44252218, 6.84910622], [53.44252457, 6.84910649], [53.44252783, 6.84910729], [53.44253168, 6.84910888], [53.44253668, 6.84910943], [53.44254088, 6.84910976], [53.44254363, 6.84910898], [53.44254612, 6.84910996], [53.44254803, 6.84910946], [53.44255004, 6.84910945], [53.44255416, 6.84910766], [53.44256019, 6.84910343], [53.44256469, 6.84909908], [53.44256753, 6.84909764], [53.44257106, 6.84909639], [53.44257482, 6.84909654], [53.44257861, 6.84909769]];

var locations2 = [[53.44241609, 6.84913974], [53.44241894, 6.84913726], [53.44242156, 6.84913385], [53.44242473, 6.84913076], [53.44242859, 6.84912721], [53.44243324, 6.84912446], [53.44243724, 6.84912303], [53.44243994, 6.84912206], [53.44244199, 6.84911994], [53.44244474, 6.84911928], [53.44244757, 6.8491193], [53.44245181, 6.84911968], [53.44245596, 6.84912085], [53.44246139, 6.84912072], [53.4424669, 6.84912142], [53.44247222, 6.84912279], [53.4424778, 6.84912454], [53.44248644, 6.84912644], [53.44249062, 6.84912761], [53.44249409, 6.84913057], [53.44249746, 6.84913362], [53.44250197, 6.84913592], [53.44250901, 6.84913629], [53.44251198, 6.84913792], [53.44251293, 6.84913988], [53.44251458, 6.84914126], [53.44251596, 6.8491434], [53.44251778, 6.84914727], [53.44251988, 6.8491501], [53.44252248, 6.8491531], [53.44252517, 6.84915473], [53.44252316, 6.84915181], [53.44252377, 6.84915124], [53.4425233, 6.84914949], [53.44252341, 6.84914848], [53.44252276, 6.84914827], [53.44252397, 6.84914868], [53.4425216, 6.84914477], [53.44252001, 6.84914287], [53.44252107, 6.84914273], [53.44251986, 6.84913869], [53.44251841, 6.84913463], [53.44251482, 6.84912822], [53.44251525, 6.84912649], [53.4425148, 6.84912465], [53.44251483, 6.84912049], [53.44251625, 6.84911749], [53.44251677, 6.84911403], [53.4425187, 6.84910978], [53.44252028, 6.84910694], [53.44252218, 6.84910622], [53.44252457, 6.84910649], [53.44252783, 6.84910729], [53.44253168, 6.84910888], [53.44253668, 6.84910943], [53.44254088, 6.84910976], [53.44254363, 6.84910898], [53.44254612, 6.84910996], [53.44254803, 6.84910946], [53.44255004, 6.84910945], [53.44255416, 6.84910766], [53.44256019, 6.84910343], [53.44256469, 6.84909908], [53.44256753, 6.84909764], [53.44257106, 6.84909639], [53.44257482, 6.84909654], [53.44257861, 6.84909769]];

locations1.map(function(l) {
  return l.reverse();
});

locations2.map(function(l) {
  return l.reverse();
});

// ---------------------------
//Defining Map 1 and Events
// ---------------------------
var route1 = new ol.geom.LineString(locations1)
    .transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var routeCoords1 = route1.getCoordinates();
var routeLength1 = routeCoords1.length;

var routeFeature1 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'route',
  geometry: route1
});
var geoMarker1 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'geoMarker',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords1[0])
});
var startMarker1 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords1[0])
});
var endMarker1 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords1[routeLength1 - 1])
});

var styles1 = {
  'route': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8]
    })
  }),
  'icon': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png'
    })
  }),
  'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      snapToPixel: false,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2
      })
    })
  })
};

var animating1 = false;
var speed1, now1;
var speedInput1 = document.getElementById('speed1');
var startButton1 = document.getElementById('start-animation1');

var vectorLayer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [routeFeature1, geoMarker1, startMarker1, endMarker1]
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    // hide geoMarker if animation is active
    if (animating1 && feature.get('type') === 'geoMarker') {
      return null;
    }
    return styles1[feature.get('type')];
  }
});

var map1 = new ol.Map({
  target: document.getElementById('map1'),
  loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
  view: new ol.View(),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer1
  ]
});
map1.getView().fit(
    vectorLayer1.getSource().getExtent(), map1.getSize(),
    {padding: [30, 5, 5, 5]});
var center1 = map1.getView().getCenter();

var moveFeature1 = function(event) {
  var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
  var frameState = event.frameState;

  if (animating1) {
    var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now1;
    // here the trick to increase speed is to jump some indexes
    // on lineString coordinates
    var index = Math.round(speed1 * elapsedTime / 1000);

    if (index >= routeLength1) {
      stopAnimation1(true);
      return;
    }

    var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords1[index]);
    var feature = new ol.Feature(currentPoint);
    vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, styles1.geoMarker);
  }
  // tell OL3 to continue the postcompose animation
  map1.render();
};

function startAnimation1() {
  if (animating1) {
    stopAnimation1(false);
  } else {
    animating1 = true;
    now1 = new Date().getTime();
    speed1 = speedInput1.value;
    startButton1.textContent = 'Cancel Animation';
    // hide geoMarker
    geoMarker1.setStyle(null);
    // just in case you pan somewhere else
    map1.getView().setCenter(center1);
    map1.on('postcompose', moveFeature1);
    map1.render();
  }
}

function stopAnimation1(ended) {
  animating1 = false;
  startButton1.textContent = 'Start Animation';

  // if animation cancelled set the marker at the beginning
  var coord = ended ? routeCoords1[routeLength1 - 1] : routeCoords1[0];
  /** @type {ol.geom.Point} */
  (geoMarker1.getGeometry())
  .setCoordinates(coord);
  //remove listener
  map1.un('postcompose', moveFeature1);
}

startButton1.addEventListener('click', startAnimation1, false);


// ---------------------------
//Defining Map 2 and Events
// ---------------------------
var route2 = new ol.geom.LineString(locations2)
    .transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var routeCoords2 = route2.getCoordinates();
var routeLength2 = routeCoords2.length;

var routeFeature2 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'route',
  geometry: route2
});
var geoMarker2 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'geoMarker',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords2[0])
});
var startMarker2 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords2[0])
});
var endMarker2 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords2[routeLength2 - 1])
});

var styles2 = {
  'route': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8]
    })
  }),
  'icon': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png'
    })
  }),
  'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      snapToPixel: false,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2
      })
    })
  })
};

var animating2 = false;
var speed2, now2;
var speedInput2 = document.getElementById('speed2');
var startButton2 = document.getElementById('start-animation2');

var vectorLayer2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [routeFeature2, geoMarker2, startMarker2, endMarker2]
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    // hide geoMarker if animation is active
    if (animating2 && feature.get('type') === 'geoMarker') {
      return null;
    }
    return styles2[feature.get('type')];
  }
});

var map2 = new ol.Map({
  target: document.getElementById('map2'),
  loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
  view: new ol.View(),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer2
  ]
});
map2.getView().fit(
    vectorLayer2.getSource().getExtent(), map2.getSize(),
    {padding: [30, 5, 5, 5]});
var center2 = map2.getView().getCenter();

var moveFeature2 = function(event) {
  var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
  var frameState = event.frameState;

  if (animating2) {
    var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now2;
    // here the trick to increase speed is to jump some indexes
    // on lineString coordinates
    var index = Math.round(speed2 * elapsedTime / 1000);

    if (index >= routeLength2) {
      stopAnimation2(true);
      return;
    }

    var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords2[index]);
    var feature = new ol.Feature(currentPoint);
    vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, styles2.geoMarker);
  }
  // tell OL3 to continue the postcompose animation
  map2.render();
};

function startAnimation2() {
  if (animating2) {
    stopAnimation2(false);
  } else {
    animating2 = true;
    now2 = new Date().getTime();
    speed2 = speedInput2.value;
    startButton2.textContent = 'Cancel Animation';
    // hide geoMarker
    geoMarker2.setStyle(null);
    // just in case you pan somewhere else
    map2.getView().setCenter(center2);
    map2.on('postcompose', moveFeature2);
    map2.render();
  }
}

function stopAnimation2(ended) {
  animating2 = false;
  startButton2.textContent = 'Start Animation';

  // if animation cancelled set the marker at the beginning
  var coord = ended ? routeCoords2[routeLength2 - 1] : routeCoords2[0];
  /** @type {ol.geom.Point} */
  (geoMarker2.getGeometry())
  .setCoordinates(coord);
  //remove listener
  map2.un('postcompose', moveFeature2);
}

startButton2.addEventListener('click', startAnimation2, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>
Map 1
</h1>
<div id="map1" class="map"></div>
<label for="speed1">
  speed:&nbsp;
  <input id="speed1" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="60">
</label>
<button id="start-animation1">Start Animation</button>

<h1>
Map 2
</h1>
<div id="map2" class="map"></div>
<label for="speed2">
  speed:&nbsp;
  <input id="speed2" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="60">
</label>
<button id="start-animation2">Start Animation</button>
```